# Read NDEF Message from Android/IOS using NFC Reader

Tags: android, ios, nfc

I want to transfer a tiny bit of data from my phone to an NFC reader (max 256 chars). It seems that IOS and Android can read/write tags, is there any way I can read these NDEF messages using an NFC reader and then process them?

Minimal experience with NFC stuff, so I apologise if I've completely misunderstood the function.

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off yes what you want to do is possible with the right hardware and software.

The NFC specification does have a peer to peer specification but forget about using that as this is not available on iOS and on Android it has been removed from Android 10 onwards.

In NFC there are 2 types of devices NFC `initiator` and NFC `target`s.

An `initiator` always starts the comms process and the `target` responds.

A lot of NFC reader type chips can be an `initiator` as well as a `target`, while Apple hardware can be both `initiator` and a `target`, Only Apple themselves can make it a `target`. On Android normal developers can make the hardware behave as both `initiator` and a `target`.

So this means the phone side can only be the `initiator` (which is used when reading and writing to NFC Tags).

Therefore the NFC reader has to be the `target`, this is mostly done by a process call Host Card Emulation (HCE) but some NFC readers can handle this in hardware without the Host CPU being involved.

A lot of this can be done with anything based on the PN532 chip with it's "ISO/IEC14443-4 Type A PICC" mode, where is behaves like a Type 4A Tag with the help of it's Host CPU

I would ignore the other emulation modes like Mifare Classic and Felica emulation as these are less supported on reader hardware.

Once you have the reader setup in the right mode and software written to respond in the right fashion, then on the phone side you just write to what looks like a Type 4 tag to send data and read to receive data.

Comment: Oh dear, well this doesn't sound good. Hmmm. Looks like we're going to have to think of an alternative solution to this. Thanks very miuch!

Comment: As I said this is possible but an advanced NFC topic, an alternative that has wider support on the phone side is to use QR codes, there is a lot more info about generating and reading QR codes from a camera than there is about this advanced NFC topic. Or now sending/receiving data is better using Bluetooth or Wifi Direct

Comment: The problem we have is, that we would ideally be able to transfer some data on IOS/Android without needing internet. Bluetooth is a bit of a pain because pairing is required, and I'm not really sure what Wifi Direct is! We can stick to using the QR code solution but were hoping for a more elegant alternative.

Comment: Wifi Direct is basically a way for 2 devices to negotiate how to setup a temporary Wifi access point for transfer data between 2 devices (can be manually done using what is also known as a wifi hotspot). The problem with NFC is that a lot of low end smartphones don't have NFC on them still, so you probably would still want QR codes as a backup for devices without NFC.

Comment: @all, any idea how to transfer photo/file for iphone to iphone which support nfc read/write ? And what about NFC image/file sharing iPhone to Android or vice-versa ? I meant, i want to communicate with other phone(contains NFC) only, no external NFC tag/reader. My intension is work with/no connection hassle. Please, suggest me all options. Thanks.