# Android Studio, pass String (username) from Android phone with NFC to another Android phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nfc, nfc-p2p

I am searching for 3 days now, and still I don't find anything that is what I want. Maybe it's not possible? But to accept that, I have to ask here.

I have a project, where I want to exchange usernames to both phones, phone 1 gets username of phone 2 and the other way. I tried many tutorials where NFC Reader is used, but none of them work, like it can't read the sended NFC message or whatever.

I don't really know what's the best way to send a String from phone to phone (which never had a bluetooth or WifiDirect connection, and I don't really want to create that connection).

Do you guys have tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read NDEF Message from Android/IOS using NFC Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72153850/read-ndef-message-from-android-ios-using-nfc-reader)

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the link. Actually yes, it answers my question that this is possible, and yes it describes it too, but I actually need examples how they are made or maybe existing projects because I am very new to using NFC. I don't really understand how to make a phone a initiator and a target.