React native NFC not working between ios and android
I have separated tsx files: AppleTechRequest.tsx for iPhone and AndroidTechRequest.tsx for Android.
When I call the function on iOS:
const startTechRequest = () => {
    NfcManager.requestTechnology([NfcTech.Ndef, NfcTech.NdefFormatable]).then(
      (data: any) => {
        NfcManager.getTag().then((tag: any) => {
          console.log('Apple::Tag', tag);
        });
      },
    );
  };

And on Android I call:
const writeNdef = async () => {
    try {
      const message = 'Hello from S24 Ultra';
      const record = Ndef.textRecord(message);
      const bytes = Ndef.encodeMessage([record]);

      console.log('Android::Requesting');

      const tech = await NfcManager.requestTechnology(
        [NfcTech.Ndef, NfcTech.NdefFormatable]
      );

      console.log('Android::Requested');

      await NfcManager.ndefFormatableHandlerAndroid.formatNdef(bytes);

      await NfcManager.ndefHandler.writeNdefMessage(bytes);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log('Android::Write Ndef::Catch', ex);
    } finally {
      console.log('Android::Write Ndef::Finally');
    }
  };

There's the following behavior:
iPhone logs: Apple::Tag {}
Android logs: Android::Requesting. it doesn't reach to the next log message

NFC does not work like that, I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/72154405/2373819 each side of the NFC communication behaves differently you cannot write on one side and read on the other. Also iOS NFC implementation is lacking so it does not matter what programming language you use.

This question is similar to: Is this possible to send NFC signal from NFC read/writer to Iphone. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Andrew thanks for your answer. Can't mobile phone act as a NFC tag?

Yes the hardware is capable on Android and on iOS of acting as a NFC tag, but on iOS Apple have restricted that capability to themselves and a very select few major partners. On Android any developer can make it behave as a specific type of NFC tag, but how to do this is very different to reading/writing a Tag. As an example for Android look at https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid . So iOS to iOS is not possible, if one of the phones is Android then possible but complicated.
